# Screen recorder isn't working - start recording but stops immediately

Tags: android-studio

When I press the screen recorder I get into the "Screen Recorder Options" window. But after I press the "Start Recording" button, the timer of the screen recorder appears for one second, the time isn't running and then the window is closed and i transferred to the "Save as" window. When i try to save and open the saved record (which is actually nothing) I get an error - "Unexpected error while copying video recording from device: Remote object doesn't exist".

In the "Event Log" I get the message - "Error during Sync: Remote object doesn't exists!".

I just change phone to Oneplus 10 and updated Android Studio to the Dolphin version - before that the recorder worked fine.

I tried to kill and start the ADB by the CMD.
I tried to switch cables and ports.
I tried to change the way the phone is connected to the computer (charging/transfer media/transfer photos etc.).
I tried to close and reopen Android Studio.

I will mention that the "Screen Capture" works fine.

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you.